# Changing from wildcard app to explicit ID app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I have created an app and it doesn't use anything like iAPs, GameCenter, Push Notifications... So I left to Xcode to manage profiles and everything.

But I decided to make an app with an explicit ID. Still, after I did this in iTunesConnect and changed bundle ID appropriately, when I click on Xcode Managed Profile button (under Signing section on General tab), I see this:

[image]

I can say that right bundle ID is matched, but I though I should see something like:

iOS Provisioning Profile : com.blahblah.myappname

App ID com.blahblah.myappname

Also, when I try to validate the app after archiving, I get this error:

[image]

I have many other apps (with explicit IDs) for which I left Xcode to manage signing automatically. The only difference is, that I haven't used explicit app ID from the start... How to make the Xcode to point to the right app ID, without disabling automatic code signing feature?

By the way, I have an Admin role in my team...

Comment: Do you have multiple developer accounts set up in Xcode?  Have you added any entitlements that would make Xcode decide you need an explicit ID in your provisioning profile?  If not, Xcode will simply pick the best profile for the app, which would still be a profile with the wildcard ID.  Your wording seems a little confusing.  Your app always has an explicit ID; however, you can choose to sign the app with a profile linked to either a wildcard or an explicit ID.  The app must have a single, unique bundle ID.

Comment: @wottle I have one account, with two teams, (personal, and the other where I have a role of a Member). I haven't really added any entitlements so far... If that is a reason why Xcode picked profile with a wildcard ID, then I guess my question is answered. Another issue (Permission failure) was related to certificates & private key pair... Once I had both in my Keychain, that part worked (private key was missing).

Comment: I believe it is.  I've never done any tests, but I know iOS, when **running** an application, only cares if there is a valid provisioning profile on the device that is valid for the app (could be a wildcard ID in the profile, or an explicit ID).  As for automatic code signing, I don't know what logic Xcode uses to pick when there are multiple valid options for the signing. My guess would be the most flexible option (the wildcard one).  When you do an iOS Distribution build, it must be an explicit ID in the profile, though.

Answer (score 0):

First create your App ID on the Apple Developer website.

Then just reference the same App ID on the Bundle identifier in the Identity tab from Xcode.

You can let Xcode automatically manage signing.

To be safe and clear create 1 production certificate for your Team.
And use it in the Signing Team part from Xcode.

You shouldn't have any issue from here.

I don't really understand your issue here or why you don't want to reference explicit App ID ?

Comment: I didn't say I don't want to reference explicit ID ... Where did you read that? ;) I said that if Xcode manages signing I get the result from the images. If I generate the certificate, provision profiles etc, everything works (eg. i am able to validate, and submit an app). So I wonder what is the problem with automatic code signing...